# Generic/DRY way to return Dictionary<string, T>

Tags: c#, csv, generics, dictionary

I have a CSV parser that takes the text line-by-line and parses it to values. I'm trying to put these values in a `Dictionary<string, T>` and return it, where T is a descendant of class `CharacterStatElement`. I *do* know what class I want T to be when I parse the CSV, but I don't want to have to rewrite/copypaste the same parser function several times to cover each Type that I want to return from it.

**Should I be writing a Generic Method for the whole thing (and if so, how do I declare that in the Method and return?) or should I be doing some other pattern here?**

Further info on the CharacterStatElement: Each of the child classes contains several fields that I figure out in the parsing using reflection. Each of the child classes has different values, but they ought to all be parsed the same way. Also, this only happens once per button click, not on a loop, so speed isn't an issue. And extracting the meat of the method to wrap it in non-generic methods doesn't do me much good, because most of the parsing method is tied to what the intended Type is by my use of reflection.

Comment: are you aware of the many powerful functions that you can use in regards to parsing a `.CSV` file.. for example `string.Split()` function allows for things of this nature and you could create a class that fits or mimics the File Structure...

Comment: if its always dervied from CharacterStatElement then why not return / pass a dictionary of string=>CharacterStatElement

Comment: I am actually using string.Split, it's the knowing of what type to cast the fields to, which I use reflection on the passed in class for.

Comment: @pm100 I read that I can't cast CharacterStatElement to a child type. This is what I think I have almost working right now, but I couldn't figure a way to get the object back as the child type later on.

Comment: sure you can cast a base type to a child type,  var child = base as ChildType, if its not a valid cast (ie base is not an instance of ChildType) then child will be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic method. In order to use reflection on the type parameter you can get a `Type` object using `typeof(T)`. That way you can instantiate that type and set properties dynamically. This is a rather bad case for generics. If you just used `object` instead of `T` everything would pretty much work the same way. That's a sign generics are not needed.

You also could pass in a "strategy" into the generic function that knows how to convert the raw parsed fields (probably a `string[]`) into a `T`. That strategy would be a `Func<string[], T>`. That way there is no reflection at all and this is a clean use case for generics.

Or, make the CSV parser return an `IEnumerable<string[]>` and deal with the conversion to `T` outside of the CSV parsing method.

Comment: Yep, ultimately, I ended up using Dictionary<string, Object>, once I figured out what my problem with casting was.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the CharacterStatElement class have a method that knows how to parse the remaining of the input line. Each derived class is overridden to perform its specific parsing process. Add any helper methods to the base class so minimize coding needed in the derived classes.

Then you process each line of the CSV file in the following way. Parse the start that gives you the information you need to decide on the correct class for parsing the whole line. Then create an instance of the correct derived class and pass in the line for processing. Then add to your global dictionary the values. Simple.

Comment: Then I guess I would just write few utility functions to parse the split strings to actual values, and switch between them based on what Type I need to get from them, hmm? That might be worth a shot, though I think I'd have to parse each field individually...